# Need to print the matching lines in different file

Tags: text-processing, split, patterns

For example, I have data like this

```
1111111
test1
test2
test3
1111111
block 1
block 2
block 3
1111111
page1
page2
page3
```

I would like to print the content as different files as shown below.

```
Test1 - File
1111111
test1
test2
test3


Block - File2
1111111
block 1
block 2
block 3


Page - File3
1111111
page1
page2
page3
```

Comment: So, is this a coding challenge? What's the prize?

Comment: Where do the headers (`Test1 - File`,`Block - File2` and `Page - File3`) come from? Should they be in the actual output files?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to split this file on `11111111`, is that correct?

Try

```
awk -vRS=1111111 'NR>1{print RS$0 >"file"NR-1}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible `awk` without headers in files:

```
awk '/^1111111/ { close("file" i); i++; } { print > "file" i; }' file
```

And second one with headers as I assume headers are constructed from the first filed after `1111111` though the last one does not seem to be like that:

```
awk '/^1111111/ { close(f); i++; s = $1; next; } { if (s) { f = "file" i; header = toupper(substr($1, 1, 1)) substr($1, 2)  " - File" i; print header ORS s > f; s = ""; } print > f; }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
csplit -zf file file.txt /^1111111/ "{*}"
```

`csplit` (coreutils) is a nice command for splitting a file
by context lines, (number of lines, patterns)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my$in=shift(@ARGV);
my$filecount=0;
my$open=0;

open(IN,'<',$in) or die $!;
while(<IN>) #reading input file
{
    if($_=~/^111/) #start new output file, if a line begins with multiple 1s
    {
        close OUT or die $! if $open==1;
        $filecount++;
        open(OUT,'>','out-'.$filecount.'.txt') or die $!;
        $open=1;
        print OUT $_;
    }
    else
    {
        print OUT $_;
    }
}
close IN or die $!;
close OUT or die $!;
```

I am sure there are more efficient ways, but this was the first that came to my mind :-)